# Is it possible to Unlock bootloader at phone with MIUI without registration?

Tags: bootloader-lock, miui

Is it possible to Unlock bootloader at phone with MIUI without registration at:
https://en.miui.com/unlock/

Comment: Most of the Xiaomi phones have a bug that lets ROM or boot.img be flashed through EDL mode without unlocking bootloader.

Comment: I found this method, but I am not sure if it is exacly unlocking bootloader: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzfAQRcJxmE

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible. You must register.

Comment: That may be so, but how did you come to this conclusion, except by searching on Google and failing to find an alternative.

Comment: @Firelord I'm own and owned several Xiaomi phones. If OP is not afraid to brick his own phone, trying to flash phone without unlocked bootloader - it is his decision. But for standard user - better to use methods provided by manufacturers. Unless we want to answer to a tons of questions like -"Why Kali Linux is so hard?"

Comment: That still doesn't answer my comment.

Comment: @Firelord sorry, eng is not my native language, but questions should have ?(question mark) at the end, am I wrong?

Comment: Okay, I think I gave a wrong impression to you. Let me try this again. When we try to answer about a possibility of something, we don't answer yes or no because a reader cannot differentiate technical yes/no with opinionated yes/no. We try to have that yes/no be backed up with reason, technical or practical, with experience and whatnot. Furthermore, an answer is not supposed to help just the OP but also future visitors with similar problem. In your case, one cannot find out "why" and any alternative, if possible.

Comment: @Firelord why I need to explain obvious things if my answer is valid? No is the answer. KISS (keep it simple, s*****), no reason to explain why, because it would not change anything - the answer will still be No.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89391/discussion-between-gravemind-and-firelord).